# Querying Randomly

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am looking to implement a raffle against the user table, where one is picked at a random amongst a pool of 100k+ users.  How would you perform the random query without a batch job or modifying the table (formula fields are fine)?  Select one at random and call it done.  Additionally, this is something scheduled, so no visualforce or javascript.

Right now I am thinking about some combination of random offset + random created date range restriction, but I wanted to see how others would go about doing this kind of thing.

Comment: I would modify the table (the User object) by adding an auto-number field to keep the code simple. Why is that not an option?

Comment: An auto number field is not an option since there are already records inserted.  Alternatively I could make a text field, data load it, and use a trigger to keep it incrementing -- but that is more work then should be needed.  I am thinking some type of creative formula field would do the trick here.

Comment: I see what you mean though there are approaches like http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Backfill-an-autonumber-custom-field-to-existing-data/td-p/198283. At least that leaves the auto-numbering working in for future User additions.

Comment: Are there any fields on User that you could use? Example: Assuming everyone has a unique Phone Extension number you could generate a random number that would select the user by their extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an auto-number field (see comments on original question):

- Add an auto-number field to User selecting the "Generate Auto Number for existing records" checkbox to populate the field for the existing Users.

Then use it from Apex code:

- Generate say 10 random numbers between the min and max values of that auto-number field obtained using an aggregate query.
- Query for the Users that match those numbers and also have IsActive=true.
- Take the first one or if there are none (because a lot of users have been de-activated) query again and keep querying until one is found.

Comment: Keith, a colleague pointed out to me that if you create a custom auto-number field, there is actually an option to generate auto numbers for existing records.  With this tweak, your answer provides the level of ease and scalability I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.  I think this is an interesting question and id be curious in other answers however.

Comment: Glad you pointed that out I'd never noticed it... I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a VF page with `ReadOnly="true"` (so you can query up to 1 million records), and do something like:

```
public User theLuckyUser {get;set;}

list<User> userList=[SELECT id
                     FROM User];

integer theChosenOne=math.round(math.random()*userList.size());
theLuckyUser=userList[theChosenOne];
```

You can't do a DML update to update `theLuckyUser`, but you can read it off on the VF page.  ...And if you really need to update that record, pass `theLuckyUser.Id` to another VF page that does the updating for you.

Comment: This is a very cool answer!  Ideally I would be doing this with scheduled apex, I will add that to the question.

Comment: Not sure that querying 100,000 ids and then throwing 99,999 of them away is the kindest use of sf servers...

Comment: isn't that what we're paying for?

Comment: and you're only being mean for like 50 ms ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)╯

Comment: You are absolutely right. Made the comment to (hopefully) give someone cutting and pasting the solution for a less appropriate circumstance pause for thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [OFFSET](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm) clause to do something like the following:

```
Integer winningOffset = Math.round(Math.random() * amountOfUsers)
User winner = [select Id, Name from User where isActive=true LIMIT:1 OFFSET:winningOffset];
```

But the downside is that you would need to do a query to count the users before doing the query above

Comment: I believe the offset statement has a limit of 2k.  Using a series of offsets could be an option.